# Possible to monitor multiple clicks on a dynamic link?

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic list of stories/links that I am displaying within a JQuery accordion which is controlled by this script -

```
$('.newsDesc').hide();
   $('.newsRow a.newsTitle ').click(function(){


           $('.newsDesc').slideUp();
           $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
           return false;
   });
```

One click on the a.newsTitle link reveals a div containing the story, though once clicked the story remains 'open' until the user clicks on a further link. I would like the script to hide the story again via second click on the same link.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll have to provide more information. How about a http://jsfiddle.net for us to work with?

Comment: Posting your html will definitely help get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should hopefully do what you want:

```
$('.newsDesc').hide();
$('.newsRow a.newsTitle').click(function(){
   var newsDesc = $(this).parent().next();
   $('.newsDesc').not(newsDesc).slideUp();
   newsDesc.slideToggle();
   return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cAqTC/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toggle methods, toggle slide for example
Look at [this link](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) for the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach - is to store counter in DOM elements data. Even more easier, if we are talking about binary state - we bind on specific class and trigger that class, thus changing the event triggered. This even works with more states, but I strongly recommend to stop on two. But for example, the idea is

```
$("a.link.stateA").live("click", function() {
   //if there are two state only, it is most probably better to use toggleClass
   $(this).removeClass("stateA").addClass("stateB");
   .....
});

$("a.link.stateB").live("click", function() {
  $(this).removeClass("stateB").addClass("stateC");
  .....
});

$("a.link.stateC").live("click", function() {
  //we are back!!!
  $(this).removeClass("stateC").addClass("stateA");
  .....
});
```

The more complex approach -  is to write a special event. This is less popular, quite complicated, to be honest, I'm not so courage to call it core functional which hardly will change, but nevertheless, check tripleclick event in [this doc](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/).

Comment: Is that really easier than just using slideToggle?

Comment: It depends on the specific task, but the short answer is yes. It is more flexible. Matching on parent().next() or any likewise "class-agnostic" selector is almost always worser. Imagine next day manager came up and asks to change slide to something else. It is almost always better know how it is done in general.